# An extra input field is added at the footer of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've included **textAngular-rangy.min.js** and **textAngular.min.js** in my jsp page (using angular JS in my app). Though no text area is there in that page. When the page is loaded, an unwanted input field is visible at the bottom mentioned below:

`<input id="textAngular-editableFix-010203040506070809" class="ta-hidden-input" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1">`

What can be the reason of putting this field here?

Comment: did you include textangular.css? it's more related to css https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/287

Comment: `ta-hidden-input` makes it hidden, it's used by textangular for processing data. So if you include the css it must disappear

Comment: thanks a lot! I missed including the textangular.css!

Comment: Just added it as an answer for others reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `textangular.css` in your project to make the textbox hidden.

The input textbox has a css class `ta-hidden-input` which will be hidden by the styles mentioned in`textangular.css`.